# Android Virtual Devices not showing in Xamarin Studio

Tags: android, macos, xamarin, cross-platform

I have created a cross platform Xamarin Studio project for iOS and Android. Sources for shared code, Android and iOS all appear in the Solution browser. However only iOS simulators appear in the device selection popup for where to run the app. There is no Android options that appear.

I have tried creating and starting AVDs manually, but nothing shows up.

How do I run the app in an Android Virtual Device?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Solution's Startup Project to the Android-based one and the Devices will change from iOS to Android devices:

[image]